# jdbctemplate query cursor not before the first row

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I have the following code. It simply executes a query then import to the other database, the second part is irrelevant in my question/problem.
As I see by default jdbcTemplate.query() set Cursor **before** the first element. I don't know where is my mistake, but this code skips the first row since the cursor initial state @first element. So when the while (resultSet.next()) { starts its skip the first element....

I tried to force to move the cursor

> resultSet.beforeFirst();

but it throws error.
Currently I check the Cursor position before the loop and I also thinking about to replace with a do {} while().

```
        jdbcTemplate.query(sqlPull, resultSet -> {
        List<List<Object>> batch = new ArrayList<>();
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

        int batchCount = 1;
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        if (resultSet.getRow() == 1) {
            addAllColumnsToArray(resultSet, batch, columnCount);
        }
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            addAllColumnsToArray(resultSet, batch, columnCount);

            if (batch.size() >= 10000) {
                callRestAPI(batch);
                VaadinSqlApplication.logger.info("Commit batch: " + batchCount++);
                insertTableToDb(sqlPush, push, batch);
                batch.clear();
            }
        }
        callRestAPI(batch);
        VaadinSqlApplication.logger.info("Commit final batch.  " + batchCount);
        insertTableToDb(sqlPush, push, batch);
        batch.clear();
    });
```

....

```
    private void addAllColumnsToArray(ResultSet resultSet, List<List<Object>> batch, int columnCount)
        throws SQLException {
    List<Object> row = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        row.add(resultSet.getObject(i));
    }
    batch.add(row);
}
```

Comment: You don't need the if-condition before while loop. Remove it and check.

Comment: I second the previous comment. Also, although probably irrelevant I would specify which database are you using and the maven artifact you use to connect to such database, just in case there's a problem with one of them.

Comment: as i mentioned the if condition added after this problem occoured. I also think its not needed, but withoutot it the first row not skip because the while loop start with a next().
the database system is mostly postgresql, but this error occours also in oracle

Answer (score 0):

You can try `do{...}while()`

```java
// ...
do{
    addAllColumnsToArray(resultSet, batch, columnCount);

    if (batch.size() >= 10000) {
        callRestAPI(batch);
        VaadinSqlApplication.logger.info("Commit batch: " + batchCount++);
        insertTableToDb(sqlPush, push, batch);
        batch.clear();
    }
}while(resultSet.next());
//...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).